# regexmatch impossible behaviour return false while comparing the cell to itself?

Tags: google-sheets, syntax, boolean, range

[image]

How can the regexmatch return false while comparing the cell to itself?

part of the text in the cell:

```
<p>כלבים וילדים מאז ומתמיד נתפסו כדבר חמוד ומתוק מאין כמוהו, בטח כשמדובר בחיבור ביניהם בגילאים הצעירים יותר; אלא שלמרות זאת, חיבור בין כלבים וילדים עלול להפוך למן נטל בעיני ההורים ה'עייפים' שלמעשה נדרשים לטפל בנפש נוספת כתוצאה מצירוף בעל חיים לחיקם.</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>אולם כפי שכולנו כבר יודעים, לא הכל בחיים הוא שחור ולבן – <a href=""http://www.goodhousekeeping.com/life/pets/g5138/best-family-dogs/"" target=""_blank"" rel=""noreferrer noopener"" aria-label=""טיפול נכון ומתן הנחיות מתאימות לילדכם (נפתח בטאב חדש)"">טיפול נכון ומתן הנחיות מתאימות לילדכם</a> עלול להקנות מיומנויות וכלים מצוינים להמשך חייו של האחרון כאדם ערכי ואחראי ביותר.</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```

Comment: The second argument defines a **regular expression**, which means that some characters have special meanings. Consider: Does the text `^[0-9]+$` match the regular expression `^[0-9]$+`? (No, because `^`, `[`, `]`, `-`, `$`, and `+` are not in the character class `[0-9]`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for comparing cell to itself use:

```
=L1=L1
```

keep in mind that certain characters of regex input need to be escaped...